# Angular2 apply css based on component selector name

Tags: css, angular, sass, ng2-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using ngx-bootstrap datepicker which has daypicker, monthpicker and yearpicker as inner component. I want to apply css to a table which is present inside daypicker.

```
<custom-datepicker>

<datepicker> //ngx-bootstrap datepicker component
    <daypicker>
        <table>
            //rows, want to apply some css to only this table
        </table>
    </daypicker>
    <monthpicker>
        <table>
            //rows
        </table>
    </monthpicker>
    <yearpicker>
        <table>
            //rows
        </table>
    </yearpicker>
</datepicker>

</customdatepicker>
```

**CustomDatePickerComponent.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'custom-datepicker',
    templateUrl: 'custom-datepicker-component.html',
    styleUrls: ['custom-datepicker-component.scss'],
})

export class CustomDatePickerComponent {

}
```

**custom-datepicker-component.html**

```
<datepicker></datepicker>
```

**custom-datepicker-component.scss**

```
//I want to apply this css to a table which is inside daypicker. As of now it's applying to all the tables
table {
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at `/deep/`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a css class to your table:

```
<datepicker> //ngx-bootstrap datepicker component
    <daypicker>
        <table class="new-class">
            //rows, want to apply some css to only this table
        </table>
    </daypicker>
...
```

and then use the regular class selector:

```
.new-class {
    // your styling
}
```

Alternatively add a class to your datepicker or daypicker like so:

```
<datepicker class="new-class">
...
```

And use descendant selector:

```
.new-class table {
    // your styling
}
```

Comment: date picker component is from ngx-bootstart datepicker library and I can't add/modify anything.

Comment: Adding a css class does not change the component itself. In this case it is just a flag for the css engine to select it. My answer does not consider the case of using scss.

Answer (score 0):

it's as simple as this, using component name it's self we can apply css

**custom-datepicker-component.scss**

```
daypicker {
  table {
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
datepicker > daypicker > table {
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
```